# How to easily create reports and comparisons from JMeter .csv data files?

Tags: csv, reporting, jmeter, load-testing

I guess my problem is very common but I still haven't found an elegant solution for it. I have  one test plan and one thread group is one test scenario. I have Listeners in each thread group that generate .csv data, per Listener, into their own thread group folder. So each "test run" has a its own folder where Listeners generate .csv data.

I would like to easily create Excel graphs from those .csv data files, maybe even so that consecutive runs could be compared against one-another in the same graph. In the end its about generating graphs easily from the data, and verifying how different application settings perform against one-another.

Any easy solution to this? I don't think we should all create our own .csv parsers :) Thanks!

Comment: Have you used loadosophia.org?

Comment: It looks good but I cannot upload client data to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may want to try [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com), it takes Excel files as data sources, let you create SQL queries against them and can spit back the results to Excel, either static or dynamic, and even it can create pivot tables with charts.